# draggable grids with grid reordering functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Folks,

I have a requirement in which I have multiples grids(dynamic) in a page, and I need to do below functionalities.

1. adding dynamic rows within grid
2. grid rows can be dragged to any other grid
3. and even grid themselves can be drag and order it among other grids.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out https://codepen.io/ettrics/pen/QbPEeg

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/various/drag-and-drop-rows-between-two-grids